# what's the purpose or meaning of >: in scala

Tags: scala

Such as List.contains ,here is the source code from scala api.

```
 def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean = {
   var these = this
   while (!these.isEmpty) {
     if (these.head == elem) return true
     these = these.tail
   }
   false
```

I understand the inter code theory, But what's about type `A1 >: A` ?

I guess `>:` just like `isInstanceOf` or something like to limit the input param's type?

Could some one give a concise explanation or some docs so i can get some research

Answer (score 3):

The meaning:

`A1` is the nearest common ancestor of `A` and supplied argument type.

The purpose:

since `List` is declared as `List[+A]` where `+A` means "covariant on type A", using `A` as an argument type is not allowed:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class List[+A] {
  def m(x: A) = x
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:15: error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value x
         def m(x: A) = x
```

**UPDATE**

Naive explanation why not (just a guess, it's hard to prove since compiler won't allow it):

```
class List[+A] {
  def m(x: A) = x
}

class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Pear extends Fruit

// list is covariant, which means
// List[Fruit] is a supertype of List[Apple]
val l: List[Fruit] = new List[Apple]
// i.e. l.m has to accept Fruit
l.m(new Pear) // Apple?
```

in reality:

```
class List[+A] {
  def m[A1 >: A](x: A1) = x
}

...

l.m(new Pear) // Fruit, the nearest common ancestor of Apple and Pear
```

Comment: I was puzzled by the contains method signature vis a vis its behaviour of accepting an argument of any type whatsoever. So, the contains method is *not* type safe. Was there no way for the designers to make the contains method type safe?

Comment: Why isn't it type safe? In my last example what is returned is not `Object`, it's the nearset common ancestor of `Pear` and `Apple`. So it's not _any_ type.

Comment: Lets say `val ls: List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4)`. Now according to the `contains` method signature the argument of type `A1` has to be a super type of `Int`. But, we can pass an argument of any type whatsoever to `contains` and the compiler doesnt complain. This is confusing to me.

Comment: So what's wrong? `List[Int]` is a subtype of `List[Any]`, so if you call `List(1).contains(new Pear)` it's a valid call (the result is obviously `false`). Both `1` and `new Pear` are instances of `Any`, so you can apply `==`.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious here. If we have a List[Int] then the `A` in the contains signature is an Int. And  the signature says that A1 has to be Int or a supertype of Int. But, this constraint is not holding, since I am able to pass an argument of any type to the contains method; Whats the point of having that lower bound type constraint if its allowing any type to be passed as an argument?

Comment: In my previous comment `A1` will be `Any` (the nearest common ancestor of `Int` and `Pear`, i.e. `Any` _is_ a supertype of `Int`), and I can pass `new Pear` since `Pear` is a subtype of `Any`. `A1` defines how you see `x` inside the method and what you can do with it. Even if it's `Pear` all information about it is lost inside `contains` and almost the only thing you can do is `==`.

Comment: Hmm, what if the contains method signature was: `def contains[A1](elem: A1): Boolean` would it have made any difference to its behavior? I guess not, because just like before any type of argument can be passed in.

Comment: It may not make much difference in `contains`, but consider `(new Pear) :: List(new Apple)`, do you want to get `List[Any]` or `List[Fruit]`? Try to implement it, it's worth the effort. And yes, `1 :: List(new Apple)` will return `List[Any]`.

Comment: @Samar In the particular case of `contains`, yes, you are right: it could just as easily be `def contains(x: Any): Boolean`. But for methods like `::` and `++`, there is a difference because `A1` takes part in the return type.

Answer (score 0):

`A` `>:` `B`  means `B` is the lower type bound of `A`